# How to join two table and use two tables value in where clause in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I want to join with two table and i want the value where answers table submitted answer and questions table correct answer will be match.

```
$correct_answers = App\Models\Answer::join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')
->where('answers.exam_id', '=', $exam->id)
->where('answers.submitted_answer', '=', 'questions.correct_answer')
->count();
```

This my query but it's not working. But this query working in sql.

```
select COUNT(*) as Total
from `answers` 
inner join `questions` on `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id` 
where `answers`.`exam_id` = 1 and 
      `answers`.`submitted_answer` = questions.correct_answer;
```

AND

```
select *
from `answers`
inner join `questions` on `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id`
where `answers`.`exam_id` = 1 and 
      `answers`.`submitted_answer` = questions.correct_answer;
```

Where did i go wrong?

There is no result on laravel.

Comment: Already i have solved it. I have mistaken near whereColumn. I used the where clause but I have to use whereColumn. The whereColumn method may be used to verify that two columns are equal:

$correct_answers = App\Models\Answer::join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')->where('answers.exam_id', '=', $exam->id)->whereColumn('answers.submitted_answer', '=', 'questions.correct_answer')->count();